# Black outline around white text on orange background on Holo.Dialog

Tags: android, layout

My activity is defined like this:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".ShareProActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_share_pro"
        android:parentActivityName=".base.BaseActivity"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Dialog.NoActionBar">
```

I added a text view with orange background:

```
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView17"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Your friend can get 10% discount on the pro map. Click the following button to send the activation to your friend."
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:padding="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textColorHint="@android:color/white" />
```

Now it looks like this in the Nexus 5 emulator.

How is that? I want to remove the black outline - just white text on orange.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this was caused by the Phone Accessibility Setting "High Contrast Text (experimental)". I disabled that and it looks fine.

Comment: any other solution?